# fillFormValues doesn't work in mat-select

Tags: angular, typescript, select

I want to fill form value when I get by id.

I get correctly value in this function:

```
  fillFormValues(expenseCategory: ExpenseCategory): void {
    console.log('response', expenseCategory.parent_category)
    this.aa= expenseCategory.parent_category;
    console.log(this.aa.name)
    this.expenseCategoriesEditForm.get('parent_category')?.setValue(this.aa.name); //it doesn't function
    this.expenseCategoriesEditForm.get('name')?.setValue(expenseCategory.name); // function ok
  }
```

In html I have this code:

```
 <mat-select formControlName="parent_category" id="parent_category">
                      <mat-option *ngFor="let p_g of expenseCategories" [value]="p_g.id">
                        {{p_g.name}}
                      </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

I want to display in view       `this.expenseCategoriesEditForm.get('parent_category')?.setValue(this.aa.name); //it doesn't function`

Can you share with me any idea please?

Comment: Can you share your form declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i see you are trying to set value "name" here:

```
this.expenseCategoriesEditForm.get('parent_category')?.setValue(this.aa.name);
```

But you need to use id instead of name of the "aa" object.
So code should be like:

```
this.expenseCategoriesEditForm.get('parent_category')?.setValue(this.aa.id);
```